# List contents and extract individual files from password protected archive file

Tags: macos, password, archive

I want to list contents of a compressed archive file, then choose some individual files to be extracted. Archive is password protected.

I tried Unarchiver and Keka but it seems none of them has a file manager feature like 7zip. Both apps extract the file immediately. When archive file size is big this behaviour causes a waste of time and disk space.

How can I do this on Mac OS X (Mavericks) ?

[*] There is a feature request [here](http://trac.kekaosx.com/ticket/24) for Keka for this problem but it is unfortunately 3 years old.

Answer (score 1):

Software recommendations are really off-topic for SE, as they go out of date rapidly, but, until such time as the question is put on hold...

[Better Zip](http://macitbetter.com) - $20 - can extract or add individual items, or
[Zipster](http://www.coriolis-systems.com/Zipster.php) - £10 - makes archives look & act like folders, work in progress so not all formats yet but looks like it will be good

Answer (score 0):

http://archiverapp.com
This one can do it for example.

Comment: Adding a bit of detail would help, such as the price if it's not freeware - £14 in this case